# CompTIA Network+ or A+ before CCNA

Tags: untagged

Which is the advisable one to take before going for CCNA? I know that A+ focuses more on physical aspects of computers and Network+ on the networking side. But some take A+ then get CCNA. So I'm a bit confused about this. Suggestions/answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Skip both A+ and Net+, go straight for CCNA. unless you just plan to work in a repair shop.

Answer (score 3):

frankly I thought comptia was out of business.  I would not bother with a+ or network+.  I would work on either an MCITP (I'd probably start with enterprise desktop support) and/or RHCSA and/or VCP.

Comment: +1 -- Avoid A+, I'm not one for judging people on certifications, but if people brag about their A+ cert I consider it a reason *not* to hire them.  MCITP is a good stepping stone in the direction of a CCNA certificate, but if you're solid on networking fundamentals you may want to just go for the CCNA.

Comment: Hi Jim.. Thank you for the suggestion..but I'd like to know how come you say CompTIA is out of business?

Comment: More of a statement of the lack of respect the comptia certs hold in the industry than anything.  CCNA can be written as two exams so if you're ok with paying more for the luxury of splitting the cert into two exams, then that might be a better route for you.

Answer (score 2):

**It really depends on what your interests are.** If it is networking, and your experience is limited, go with Network+, if you have some experience, go with [the CCNA](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/le3/le2/le0/le9/learning_certification_type_home.html), which you can split into two parts.

Pick something you love doing, and excel at it. The best geeks love what they do.

Answer (score 2):

The CCNA Official Exam Certification Library books do a great job covering all of the basics. The bigger question is CCENT first or CCNA right away? The CCENT will allow you to take a pair of tests with less breadth vs a single test that covers more.

The CCNA/CCENT is hands down a better starting point than the CompTIA exams.